# Registering users through php, but having issues

Tags: php, html, mysql

it's mainly another set of eyes here as I can't visibly see any errors and it isn't posting any. I am attempting to create a user registration form using PHP/SQL for part of an assignment, but when I hit register, it doesn't come up with anything, just a blank page. Before I fixed the connection, it would show the generic "Cannot connect to database".

Here is my HTML and PHP.

PHP

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'users');
define('DB_USER', 'twisted');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '********');

$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysql_error());


function CreateUser() {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $sname = $_POST['sname'];
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['passwd'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (fname,sname,username,email,passwd) VALUES ('$fname','$sname','$username','$email','$passwd')";
    $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
    if($data)
    {
        echo "Your registration was successful";
    }
}

function SignUp() {
    if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =  '$_POST[username]' AND pass = '$_POST[passwd]'") or die(mysql_error());

    if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die (mysql_error()))
    {
        CreateUser();
    } else {
        echo "You are already a registered user";
    }
}
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    SignUp();
}

?>
```

Registration Form

```
                            <form id="register-form" action="/includes/connect.php" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="fname"tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="sname""abindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="uname" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" name="passwd"  tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                                <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                        <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

**Edit:** The database exists, and these are the fields.

https://gyazo.com/d20200fdc5bd3648484f27448aaccc96

Comment: Place this at the top of your .PHP file to show error: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: If it just shows you a white page, look at your error logs.

Comment: After submitting the form, is the user inserted into the database?

Comment: `uname` != `username` and `submit` != `register-submit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your submit `<input>` a name or it won't be available using `$_POST['submit']:`

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>
```

Comment: The answer was a bit of yours, and a bit of the answer below, so thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 2):

You've also initialised `$password = $_POST['passwd'];` but used it incorrectly in your query and inserted `$passwd` instead of `$password`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (fname,sname,username,email,passwd) VALUES ('$fname','$sname','$username','$email','$passwd')";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form, the name of your post value is not corresponding to the one in the SignUp function:

```
name="uname"
function SignUp() {
    if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {
```

so the query isn't executed

Also as @Kitson88 says, another typo. Sometimes you just don't see them, it happens ;-)

Comment: The answer was a bit of yours, and a bit of the answer below, so thank you very much guys!